# How to log in a Macbook with broken screen

Tags: screen

My macbook's screen is broken. I was using it with external monitor. Currently though I'm stuck on the login screen and can't log in and the external screen is blank.

I think the problem is the language of the keyboard layout and I try changing it with FN to iterate over all the languages but still can't log in. I am wondering if it's possible that voice over can read over the options presented or if I'm using the wrong keyboard shortcut for iterating over the languages.

I attempted to close the screen but I think the sensor is busted as well as I still get a blank screen on my external monitor.

Sadly can't even enter recovery mode like this.

1. Attempted to have it speak the password that I type in but apparently that fails as well. (Chose verbosity level high.)
2. Seems the sensor for the lid isn't broken and finally I get the login screen on external monitor. For some bizarre reason the password which I always use is refused. I tried to go in recovery mode but asks for recovery key which I don't have.

Most bizarre tech problem in my life.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Simple try: Restart your system and then close the lid so the lid sensor acknowledges the lid is closed your external display should automatically become the primary display.

Comment: @Ruskes I'm pretty sure the lid sensor is also broken. I put the lid down and external screen is again blank. Not sure how I can restart it with the lid closed. As far as I know I need to press CMD + Ctrl + Power for a restart.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to reflect the current state of affairs *only*? It's quite hard for others to understand the situation right now. Also, if the issue is solved (not sure how your other question relates to this here), you may also just delete the question, or self-answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, for me the lid sensor was working. Plugging out and in the HDMI cable while the lid was closed worked. The other issue was the same password that I tried 100s of times during login even with view on external screen didn't work. Initially thought I had forgotten the password but then I went in recovery mode and the same password worked there after which the same password worked to login.

I thought it was keyboard layout related or caps lock related but no.

Thanks everyone for feedback.

Comment: @Ruskes I'm pretty sure the lid sensor is also broken.  ??? and now it is not

Comment: @Ruskes Yeah, really sorry about that. Thanks for your time. I really appreciate it.